# ImageMap using java script in webview of android but image is not fixed

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

i made an apps in android to find area of an image like ImageMap of HTML.
i have used javaScript and HTML in WebView of android. Every think is working correct. But if i touch lower mapped area of image than i reached on top of the image.

i am not able to fix the image on onClick event of html and JS in WebView of android.

Comment: post code ............... and also use webviewclient.....................for this one.

Comment: Hi i have solved this problem :)